# How can i extract the value of "token" from this JSON response with Java

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I got this response from my server. I need to extract the value of "token" from the JSON file. I want a variable to contain "hello" at the end. How can I do that in Android Studio (Java)?

PS: I have changed the token to "hello" for security sakes

```
{
"token":"hello",
"refresh_token":"hey"
}
```

Comment: are you using retrofit for api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSONObject` to get your value from your server response:

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(your response);
  jsonObject.get("token"); // this will get you the value for the key "token"
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.json.JSONObject` is the class for obtaining the JSON (Javascript Object Notation) object. 
As soon as you retrieve the response string by calling the login API, just parse the response onto JSON object and get the key (here "token" in your case) like :
`JSONObject loginJSONObject = new JSONObject(result);`
`String access_token = loginJSONObject.getString("token");`.